# Loop through Column restarting when value changes

Tags: vba, excel

I've found a couple threads with similar titles but weren't really what I am looking to do. What I'm trying to do is go through the list of numbers in Col A, and calculate the time difference using NetworkDays for the first instance the number appears in Col B ' Received On ' and the last instance the number appears in Col C ' Processed On '. After the NetworkDays calculation is done I'd like to put that value repeating in Col D on every respective row. The number of times a value will appear in Col A constantly varies, and Col A itself is several thousand lines long and constantly growing. Once that is done I need to loop through all the other different sets of numbers in Col A and repeat the process. As an example, ***39430 first appears on Row 2 and last appears on Row 7. Using Networkdays(B2,C7) gives 11 days, and so forth. After that move onto ***39383. Sample below.

[Sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sD5FS.jpg)

Below is the code I have so far. From the sample above I have to put a blank row under ***39430 in order to get the code to work, otherwise it just continues on to the bottom of the list and calculates that difference (not what I want obviously). What I'm stumped on is how to tell the loop to restart whenever the value changes in Col A and then continue on. I suspect it might be something close to  Do Until ActiveCell.Value <> Activecell.Offset(-1,0).Value but I can't quite figure it out. Also how to get the Networkdays value to repeat on every respective row.

```
Dim counter As Integer
Dim CycleTime As Long

counter = 0

Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""
counter = counter + 1


ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop

'Gives the number of rows to offset
MsgBox counter

'Shows the correct number of days difference
MsgBox WorksheetFunction.NetworkDays(Range("B2"), Range("B2").Offset(counter - 1, 1))
CycleTime = WorksheetFunction.NetworkDays(Range("B2"), Range("B2").Offset(counter - 1, 1))
Range("D2").Value = CycleTime
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

***Update***

After using the code provided for a couple of weeks I've noticed a complication that I had not thought of before. Previously, I had thought that there was always only one output doc for each input doc (not considered in scope of original question), however as shown in Sample-New image in the top box there can be more than one output doc per input doc. For the new screenshot below I've included two additional columns, Col. C 'Output Doc #' and Col. D 'Output Doc Created On'.  What I'd like to be able to do, amending the code that @YowE3K provided below, is to nest another loop that goes through Col. D 'Output Doc #' and uses NetworkDays to calculate the difference from B1 and D1 for the first group, and then B1 and D8 for the second group. As it is now, the code isn't written to handle the change and calculates everything as shown in Column F, with the ideal code resulting in Column G. The second box (in dark blue) shows a typical example where the code performs perfectly. Loops are something I'm struggling with to understand and not really sure how to even take a stab at this. Any comments to the code in a response would be very helpful. Thanks in advance.

[Sample - New](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sD5FS.jpg)

Comment: Re update:  Isn't this just a case of taking the existing code and changing "D" to "G" and "C" to "D" and `If Cells(startRow, "A").Value <> Cells(endRow + 1, "A").Value Then` to `If Cells(startRow, "A").Value <> Cells(endRow + 1, "A").Value Or Cells(startRow, "C").Value <> Cells(endRow + 1, "C").Value Then`?  And this "update" should really be a new question if this is a new requirement.

Comment: Thanks that works perfectly. Also I was unsure on the question-editing etiquette, new question makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code loops using `endRow` as the loop "counter".

`startRow` is set to the row containing the start of the current "Doc Number", and `endRow` is incremented until it is pointing at the last row for that "Doc Number".

Once `endRow` is pointing at the correct place, `CycleTime` is calculated and written to column D of each row from `startRow` to `endRow`.  `startRow` is then set to point to the beginning of the next "Doc Number".

The loop ends when a blank cell is found in column A.

```
Sub Calc()

    Dim startRow As Long
    Dim endRow As Long
    Dim CycleTime As Long

    startRow = 2
    endRow = 2
    Do
        If Cells(startRow, "A").Value <> Cells(endRow + 1, "A").Value Then
            CycleTime = WorksheetFunction.NetworkDays(Cells(startRow, "B"), Cells(endRow, "C"))
            Range(Cells(startRow, "D"), Cells(endRow, "D")).Value = CycleTime
            startRow = endRow + 1
        End If
        endRow = endRow + 1
        If Cells(endRow, "A").Value = "" Then
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop

End Sub
```

---

Edited to keep track of the first and last "Approved" record, and only update column D if one is found:

```
Sub Calc()

    Dim startRow As Long    'Start of the Doc Number
    Dim firstRow As Long    'First "approved" row
    Dim lastRow As Long     'Last "approved" row
    Dim endRow As Long      'End of the Doc Number
    Dim CycleTime As Long

    startRow = 2
    endRow = 2
    firstRow = -1
    lastRow = -1

    Do
        If Cells(endRow, "Q").Value = "Approved" Then
            'Found an "Approved" record

            'Set the first row if not already set
            If firstRow = -1 Then
                firstRow = endRow
            End If

            'Set the last row (will replace this if we find another record)
            lastRow = endRow
        End If

        If Cells(startRow, "A").Value <> Cells(endRow + 1, "A").Value Then
            If firstRow > 0 Then ' (If it is -1 then we never found an "Approved" record)
                CycleTime = WorksheetFunction.NetworkDays(Cells(firstRow, "B"), Cells(lastRow, "C"))
                Range(Cells(startRow, "D"), Cells(endRow, "D")).Value = CycleTime
            End If
            'Set up for next Doc Number
            startRow = endRow + 1
            firstRow = -1
            lastRow = -1
        End If
        'Go to next row
        endRow = endRow + 1
        'Exit when we hit a blank Doc Number
        If Cells(currentRow, "A").Value = "" Then
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: This is perfect but I found a complication. I only want this to calculate when the value in Col Q says 'Approved', otherwise the cells in columns B and C are blank and it is causing  a "Run-time error '1004' Unable to get the NetworkDays property of the WorksheetFunction class" and the code stops running on that line